# Building a GCC Cross Compiler

Tags: compiling, gcc

I'm trying to follow the [Bare Bones](http://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_Bones) tutorial on the OS Dev wiki but I'm confused on [how to build the GCC cross compiler](http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler). It says to install the source code for stuff like bintuils, GCC, GNU GMP etc, but most of it is already installed or can be installed from the software center. Do I need to install a second copy? It also said to install into $HOME/opt/cross, but I could only find /opt, and I'm assuming "cross" is a directory I'll have to make. I've never built anything through source code before, only installed from PPAs. I'm doing this for a class project.

Answer (score 2):

`mkdir -p $HOME/opt/cross` will create the directory, where you should install your cross-compilation tools. `sudo apt-get install apt-src;man apt-src` will show you how to get the source code for any package.